# PRODSECBUG-2403 RCE Vulnerability patch has not been detected! (500) get in magneto 2.4.0 security scan

Tags: magento2.4.0, security-scan-tool, security-patch

i am using magneto 2.4.0 .
While run magento security scan get this message

FAIL | Patch | RCE Vulnerability | PRODSECBUG-2403 RCE Vulnerability patch has not been detected! (500)

when try to fin patch PRODSECBUG-2403 not getting this patch. How to get this patch or to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue after upgrade 2.4.0 to 2.4.2,
In my case, my initial Magento version was 2.3.2

After upgrade 2.4.0 to 2.4.2 I had checked composer.json
it was show "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.2"
but "version": "2.3.2",
I manually updated It 2.4.2 and run the "composer update" command.
I ran after some time security scan again it was fixed for me.

you can check your composer.json